# pi4J For Orange Pi Plus 2

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, orange-pi

for a school project I recently bought an Orange Pi +2 hoping to use it to control a few electronics with the GPIO pins. I have many years of Java experience so I naturally wanted to write my code in that language. When trying to install pi4j which is a java library for raspberry pi I get this error:

```
mackenzie@OrangePI:~$ sudo java -jar LCD.jar
sudo: unable to resolve host OrangePI
Unable to determine hardware version. I see: Hardware   : sun8i,
- expecting BCM2708 or BCM2709. Please report this to projects@drogon.net
```

I was wondering if anyone had any ports for the Orange Pi and if not I will have to write my program in C. I am running Debian 8 jacer 2 as the os.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimental support for `OrangePi` is now included in the latest `Pi4J v1.2-SNAPSHOT` builds.  Please be aware that this is largely untested at this time.  Feel free to try it out and report issues to the project.

I'm afraid that the `WiringPi` port for `OrangePi (WiringOP)` may be slightly outdated and may not support the newer/latest `OrangePi` hardware models, but more testing is needed to confirm which models are working.

Comment: I'm using the latest snapshot, but still getting the 'Unable to determine hardware version.  I see: Hardware : sun8i' message when I try to use Pi4J.  Is there a config change necessary?

Answer (score 0):

I saw this post that may help you : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pi4j/T30EUL2Z10I

As I do not own this device, so I cannot verify by myself.

Comment: Ah yes I have looked at this link but it doesn't appear to actual work with the Orange Pi Plus 2.

Answer (score 0):

For Raspberry Pi there is the well-known wiringPi library, written in C, for GPIO access and control. This library has been ported for the Orange Pi. The port is called wiringPO. I wrote a simple Java class with a native method. The native method gives me access to the wiringPO library, and I use JNI to allow my java application to interact with the native method. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line:

```
GpioFactory.setDefaultProvider(new OrangePiGpioProvider());
```

before getting instance: `gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is with every orange pi, the problem is with resolv.conf in /etc/resolv.conf.
do
sudo nano /../etc/resolv.conf
and then add
nameserver 8.8.8.8
to it
and control-o to save it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).